# Curvature form on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, symplectic-geometry, line-bundles

I am trying to understand the basic construction in P. Biran's paper "Lagrangian Barriers and Symplectic Embeddings". At the begining (2.1), there is a construction which relies on the following things I would like some explanation or refference:

Suppose $(\Sigma,\tau)$ is a compact symplectic manifold and $L\rightarrow \Sigma$ a (complex) line bundle with $c_1(L)=[\tau]$. Pick any hermitian metric $h$ and define $E_L$ the unit disc bundle of $L$. Consider a connection $\nabla$ such that its curvature form is $R^{\nabla}=2\pi i\tau$. And $a^\nabla$ is the associated $\textit{transgression}$ $1$-form which satisfies certain properties.

My first question is this: Why can we find a connection with such an $R^\nabla$?
My second question is: Can you provide me with a general refference of transgression forms.

Comment: I did not make the calculations, but here is my idea: as two connections differ from a tensor, try to solve the equation $R^{\nabla + T} = 2\pi i\tau$ where the unknown is $T$.

Comment: You mean curvature, not connection. And what is this associated transgression $1$-form? The standard setting to have a transgression is a zero cohomology class.